# cURL not working with a URL in a variable

Tags: php, curl

I have a function `GetContentsCurl($url)` that usually works but I've ran into a use case with a strange issue. If I pass in a URL in a variable it doesn't work, but if I echo that variable, copy & paste the URL and paste it in as a parameter to the function it works just fine.

What would be causing this? Shouldn't the strings be identical, and thus have the exact same functionality?

```
    public static function UrlGetContentsCurl(){
    // parse the argument passed and set default values
    $arg_names    = array('url', 'timeout', 'getContent', 'offset', 'maxLen');
    $arg_passed   = func_get_args();
    $arg_nb       = count($arg_passed);
    if (!$arg_nb){
        echo 'At least one argument is needed for this function';
        return false;
    }
    $arg = array (
        'url'       => null,
        'timeout'   => ini_get('max_execution_time'),
        'getContent'=> true,
        'offset'    => 0,
        'maxLen'    => null
    );
    foreach ($arg_passed as $k=>$v){
        $arg[$arg_names[$k]] = $v;
    }

    // CURL connection and result
    $ch = curl_init($arg['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, $arg['offset']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $arg['timeout']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

    $result  = curl_exec($ch);
    $chErr = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($chErr){
        echo $chErr."<br/>";
    }
    elseif($arg['getContent']){
        return $arg['maxLen']
            ? substr($result, 0, $arg['maxLen'])
            : $result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: added the function in question

Comment: What is it that "doesn't work"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, the curl_exec returns blank if I pass the URL by variable, and returns the page just fine if I paste the URL in.

Comment: Just before the curl_init can you dump the $arg variable? I'm guessing it's not being set as you are expecting it to be. I'd look closely at the `func_get_args()` function to make sure it's doing what you expect.

Comment: thank you! figured out that a URL containing a HTML entity encoding was being passed, so naturally enough when the URL was being echoed the browser rendered &amp; as an &, should have looked at the source code.